# Como actualizo un plan de suscripción con API paypal

Tags: php, curl, paypal

Supongamos que alguien ha contratado un plan básico por 3 euros al mes, pero luego ve que el producto vale la pena y quiere pagar la opción pro por 6 euros al mes.

Parece algo lógico y deseable en casi cualquier negocio online hoy en día, y resulta que en la API de PayPal no viene bien documentado y casi no se menciona nada al respecto.

Porque yo pongo el bearer token, el id de suscripción, y el id de producto al que se va a actualizar en la solicitud curl tal cual como indica tanto en el ejemplo como en la descripción de la API y me salta:

```
{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"e86bb8f4167f9","details":[{"issue":"PLAN_PRODUCT_NOT_COMPATIBLE","description":"The old and the new plans should be for the same product."}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}
```

Y este es el código curl del cual me he basado:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-BW452GLLEP1G/revise
```

-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer " 
-d '{
"plan_id": "P-5ML4271244454362WXNWU5NQ"
}'

Esta es la documentación: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/customize/revise-subscriptions/